# Linker error: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s

Tags: ubuntu, gcc

I am trying to compile `symlinks` ([tar.gz-file](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/symlinks/symlinks_1.2.orig.tar.gz)), which is a very small tool with one line for compilation:

```
gcc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -O2 -N -s -o symlinks symlinks.c
```

which gives the error

```
....    
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The output of

```
/sbin/ldconfig -p | grep libgcc
```

is

```
libgcc_s.so.1 (libc6) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
```

and trying to include the mentioned directory directly

```
gcc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -L /lib/i386-linux-gnu/  -O2 -N -s -o symlinks symlinks.c
```

produces the same error.

Three questions:

1. Why does it not work with the first command, as the lib seems to be in the search path
2. Why does including the path itself does not help
3. How to fix this?

Comment: EDIT: The original command is as posted in the edited question.

Comment: What does 'echo $PATH' say?

Comment: I found the solution in the meantime, thanks for making your suggestion.

Comment: The given link for `symlinks` is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Omitting the option `-N`.

Comment: Why does this work? I can only figure out that [`man ld`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ld) suggests `-N` disables linking against shared libraries (among many other things).

Comment: The version of gcc installed does not provide any help of `-N` on the man pages. Without deeper investigation I cannot say what `-N` does or did.

Comment: @Alex please don't mix `gcc` and `ld` flags. They are totally different. If you want static linking in gcc, use `-static`. Also you could be interesting in `-static-libgcc`. They are tons of undocumented gcc flags because it converts virtually all input flags to internal form before reprocessing, so don't surprise on unexpected result from undocumented flags.